# Sorting Algorithm using Modified Merge sort

Tags: java, complexity, mergesort

I've been messing around with merge sort. Instead of doing a recursive division of the array I chose to keep keep track of the middle index of every three numbers. Using the index of the middle number, it sorts the numbers directly around it and then merges the consecutive portions of the array.I'm having trouble figuring out the time complexity of the sorting portion. I know it's worse than actual Merge sort, I think it's either O(2^n) or O(n^2). How do I analyze the time complexity of this sorting algorithm?

````
  import java.util.Random;

public class modifiedMergeSort {
    /**
     * Merges two sorted portions of the array (Same algorithm as conventional MergeSort)
     * @param arr the array to be sorted
     * @param p beginning index of first array
     * @param q last index of first array
     * @param r last index of second array
     */
        void merge(int arr[], int p, int q, int r) {

            // Create L ← A[p..q] and M ← A[q+1..r]
            int n1 = q - p + 1;
            int n2 = r - q;

            int[]L = new int[n1];
            int[]M = new int[n2];

            for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
                L[i] = arr[p + i];
            for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
                M[j] = arr[q + 1 + j];

            // Maintain current index of sub-arrays and main array
            int i, j, k;
            i = 0;
            j = 0;
            k = p;

            // Until we reach either end of either L or M, pick larger among
            // elements L and M and place them in the correct position at A[p..r]
            while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
                if (L[i] <= M[j]) {
                    arr[k] = L[i];
                    i++;
                } else {
                    arr[k] = M[j];
                    j++;
                }
                k++;
            }

            // When we run out of elements in either L or M,
            // pick up the remaining elements and put in A[p..r]
            while (i < n1) {
                arr[k] = L[i];
                i++;
                k++;
            }

            while (j < n2) {
                arr[k] = M[j];
                j++;
                k++;
            }
        }

    /**
     * Uses a set of three numbers and keeps track of the index of the middle number
     * Sorts each set of 3 numbers using the index of the middle number to make comparisons with the number at index i+1 and i-1
     * @param array the array to be sorted
     */
    public void triSort(int[] array){
        /**
         * Figure out how many indexes you need to keep track of
         */
        int pointersNeeded;
        if(array.length % 3 == 0){
            pointersNeeded = array.length / 3;
        }else {
            pointersNeeded = (array.length / 3) + 1;
        }

        /**
         * Find the pointers for every set of three and place in an array
         */
        int[] pointerArray = new int[pointersNeeded];
        for (int i = 0; i < pointersNeeded; i++){
            if ((1 + (i * 3)) < array.length - 1){
                pointerArray[i] = 1 + (i * 3);
            }else {
                pointerArray[i] = array.length - 1;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Sorts each set of 3 numbers
         */
        for (int pointer: pointerArray) {
            if(pointer < array.length-1){
                if (array[pointer] < array[pointer-1])
                {
                    swap(array, pointer, pointer-1);
                }

                if (array[pointer+1] < array[pointer])
                {
                    swap(array, pointer, pointer + 1);

                    if (array[pointer] < array[pointer-1])
                    {
                        swap(array, pointer, pointer - 1);

                    }
                }
            }else {
                if (((array.length - 1) - pointer)  == 0){
                    System.out.println();
                    swap(array, pointer-1, pointer);
                }

            }

        }


        int beg = 0;
        int mid;
        int right;
        /**
         * Merges two subset of the array to make 1 set and then moves the middle and right indexes to the next subset for merging
         */
        for(int i = 0; i < pointerArray.length - 1; i++){
            mid = pointerArray[i] + 1;
            right = mid + 3;
            if (pointerArray[i] >= (array.length - 1) || right > (array.length - 1)) {
                right = array.length - 1;

            }
            merge(array, beg, mid, right);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Swaps two numbers in the array
     * @param array the array
     * @param index1 the index of the first number to swap
     * @param index2 the index of the second number to swap
     */
    public void swap(int[] array, int index1, int index2){
        int temp = array[index1];
        array[index1] = array[index2];
        array[index2] = temp;
    }

    /**
     * Prints array
     * @param arr the array
     */
    static void printArray(int arr[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /**
         * Make an array with size 100,000
         */
        int[] arr =  new int[100000];

        /**
         * Fill array with nums 0-999,999
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
            arr[i] = i;
        }

        /**
         * Randomly shuffle numbers in array
         */
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
            int index = rand.nextInt(arr.length - i);
            int temp = arr[arr.length - 1 - i];
            arr[arr.length - 1 - i] = arr[index];
            arr[index] = temp;
        }

        modifiedMergeSort ob = new modifiedMergeSort();

        /**
         * Sort
         */
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ob.triSort(arr);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Sorted in: " + (end-start) + "ms");

    }
}


```
````

Comment: @superbrain No I'm leaning more towards O(n^2)